# ClosedXML is not compatible with .NETCoreApp 1.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, closedxml

I'm trying to add ClosedXML and iText7 to my .NETCore project for school. But every single time I try to install these packages I get the same error:
**One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.**

Does anyone know a solution for this problem? I work with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition. Or does anybody has a suggestion to generate Excels and pdfs with .NET Core?

Comment: Error messages clear enough. Target ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework >= 4.5 instead if you need libraries which are not yet ported to .NET Core/NETStandard

Comment: Follow https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/101 for update on .NET Standard support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML

As you can see, ClosedXML depends on .NETFramework 4.0.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/dotnet/1308/dotnet-core-future-of-dotnet-framework

Right-click on the startup project and click properties. In the application tab, click the Target framework dropdown and .NET Framework >= 4.5. You will lose the cross platform compatibility.

I personally haven't found an ideal export/import solution for excel files but maybe this might work for you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Shaman.EPPlus/

Comment: I can't change the target framework to .NET Framework >= 4.5. I ony see .NET Core 1.0 and .NET Core 1.1. I'll try to figure out how  I can choose something else. I'll  come back later... I'll also try to install your suggested package. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think that the problem is that we created a .NET Core Application. So I think that by default, you can only choose between .NET Core App 1.0 and 1.1

Comment: Oh nice!!!! It worked to install Shaman.EPPlus! You don't know how happy I am... Thanks a lot!
Do you know another library to create a PDF from that Excel? We have a template in Excel, so it's easier for us to put all values in that template and than convert that to PDF. Instead of creating a pdf from scratch...